# Access a variable in react-typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am learning react-typescript,

Code -

```
import {phones} from "../../get_phone";

interface IProps {
    phone: phones,
}

const Query1: React.FC <IProps> = ({phone}) => 
{
    console.log(phone)    
    const [model, setmodel] = useState(phone);
    console.log(model);
}
```

Is it possible to access the `model` variable from other Components and also from other typescript files?

Thanks

Comment: useState its a hook to rendering, if state change then render would be changed...but if you want a global variable, I recommend to you use contexts variables (useContext)

 u can read about it on -> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Custom Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook):

`useQuery.ts`

```
const useQuery: React.FC<IProps> = ({ phone }) => {
  const [model, setModel] = useState(phone);
  return { model, setModel }
};
```

`otherComponent.tsx`

```
const OtherComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const { model, setModel } = useQuery({ phone });

  // can use `model` here
  return <div>something</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`model`'s value is accessible only within react's render cycles. If you want to pass it to other components that's what [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) are for. If it's deeply nested components you may use [`Context Api`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for that.

Generally `models`'s value is not accessible outside of react's render cycle without really dirty hacks.